# Let node.js application directly listen to 80 port

Tags: centos, centos7, node.js

I have a node.js application I want it to directly listen to 80 port, but when I run the node app with the following command `node index.js` but with firewall running `systemctl start firewalld`. When the firewall is running I can't view the app when I access to the 80 port. But when I disable the firewall with the command `systemctl stop firewalld` I can view the app when I access the 80 port

How can I access/view my app with firewall running?

---

#### OS information

Centos 7 64-bit

Using minimal ISO

Running at VM workstation 12.5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a rule to allow port 80 traffic.

To list active zones:

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

To add the port 80 rule to the "public" zone:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
```

To list rules for the "public" zone:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
```

---

Source: https://blog.christophersmart.com/2014/01/15/add-permanent-rules-to-firewalld/